# I am learning flutter and the project is giving 'Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test

I am learning flutter and the project is giving 'Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'
It is just giving the error just in emulator and working fine in windows and browser. and this is the error I am getting while debugging in vs code
[image: Error I got while debug running the flutter application]
Can anyone please help me with this

I searched everywhere but didn't find anything to solve this issue

Comment: does [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/97/how-to-solve-android-jar-does-not-exist-error-on-flutter-android/) solve your issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run flutter doctor -v ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all run:

```
C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
```

And make sure that there are no errors.

Secondly, make:

```
C:\src\flutter>flutter create myproj
```

And follow the instructions.

The correct output should be:

```
C:\Users\hp\Projects\test>flutter create myproj
Creating project myproj...
Running "flutter pub get" in myproj...                           2.859ms
Wrote 127 files.

All done!  
In order to run your application, type:

$ cd myproj
$ flutter run
Your application code is in myproj\lib\main.dart.
```